# how to move a sub window ncurses in a main window in C language

Tags: c, ncurses

I am a beginner in C. I wanted to make a game but I'm stuck and I come to ask you for help.

I created a main window and another smaller one in main window:
[sub window in main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTDxA.png)

And I would like to move this second small window with the keys of the keyboard, that's why I made the functions move and destroy_win. Except that when I run the program, it just shows me the small window without the main window:
[no main window...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiwkG.png)

My code :

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int y, int x);

void deplacement(int height, int width, int x, int y);

void destroy_win(WINDOW *local_win);

WINDOW* mainwin;
WINDOW* my_win;

int main() {
    // Initialisation de ncurses
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);

    // Calcul des positions et tailles des fenêtres
    int height = 30;
    int width = 80;
    int y = (LINES - height) / 2;
    int x = (COLS - width) / 2;

    // Calcul des positions du carré controlé par le Joueur
    int square_height = 2;
    int square_width = 4;
    int square_y = y + (height - square_height) / 2;
    int square_x = x + (width - square_width) / 2;

    // Création de la fenêtre principale
    mainwin = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    box(mainwin, 0 , 0);
    mvwprintw(mainwin, 0, 2, " Score : 0 ");
    mvwprintw(mainwin, 0, 20, " Temps restant : 5.0s ");
    wrefresh(mainwin);

    // Création de la fenêtre du carré    
    my_win = create_newwin(square_height, square_width, square_y, square_x);
    wrefresh(my_win);
    sleep(3);

    
    deplacement(square_height, square_width, square_x, square_y);

    wgetch(my_win);
    // Libération de la mémoire et fermeture de ncurses
    delwin(my_win);
    delwin(mainwin);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}


WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int y, int x)
{   
    WINDOW *local_win;
    local_win = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    box(local_win, 0 , 0);
    wrefresh(local_win);
    return local_win;
}


void deplacement(int height, int width, int x, int y) {
    int ch = getch();    
    
    while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(2))
    {
    switch(ch)
    {   
        case KEY_LEFT:              
        destroy_win(my_win);                
        my_win = create_newwin(height, width, y,--x);   
        break;
    
        case KEY_RIGHT:
        destroy_win(my_win);
        my_win = create_newwin(height, width, y,++x);
        break;

        case KEY_UP:
        destroy_win(my_win);
        my_win = create_newwin(height, width, --y,x);
        break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
        destroy_win(my_win);
        my_win = create_newwin(height, width, ++y,x);
        break;  
    }
        wrefresh(my_win);
    }
}


void destroy_win(WINDOW *local_win)
{
    wborder(local_win, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ');

    wrefresh(local_win);
    delwin(local_win);
}
```

So I wanted to know how I could fix this error by displaying the main window with the borders, please and thanks.

Comment: `wgetch` and `getch` refresh the window that they're running in; to update the other windows, you would use `wnoutrefresh` (look for those to see that this is a duplicate)

Comment: This answers your question: [Moving windows in ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445527/moving-windows-in-ncurses) - one of several duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I run the program, it just shows me the small window without the main window

> So I wanted to know how I could fix this error by displaying the main window

The calls of `getch()` in `deplacement` implicitly refresh `stdscr`, overwriting your windows; use `wgetch(my_win)` instead. Then we also need `keypad(local_win, TRUE);` in `create_newwin`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I modified my function `deplacement` according to your advice using wgetch(my_win) and it work